# Windows 10: app does not complete UN-install and remains in the apps list

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, webstorm

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can only find a) how to uninstall Windows 10, or b) how to uninstall an app.

Problem:

I uninstalled the Webstorm 11 EAP (beta preview before release) and its uninstall option is broken: The files have been removed, but it remains in the list of apps including in System -> Apps & features.

How do I get rid of the leftovers?

*EDIT:* I found out how to remove it from the menu, simply by removing the link in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\JetBrains`. Still have to remove it from the app list in the "System" dialog — **which is my actual question**.

Comment: I suggest you contact the author for assistance.  You should be able to just manually remove it from the list (CCleaner) has that capability.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I submitted a support ticket with JetBrains. I'll update this question (for the record) if they are able to provide a solution.

Comment: Please don't [edit] your question to include the answer. [SU] requires seperate questions and answers. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @DavidPostill That is true only *if I actually have an answer*. My question was about the list of apps (see the headline), and I don't have a solution for that *at all*!

Comment: @MörreNoseshine - I suggested a program that will simply remove the entry.  If the program data is gone from the EAP, then when you install the stable Webstorm 11 build, anything that might still exist will be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Using [Wise Program Uninstaller](http://www.wisecleaner.com/wise-program-uninstaller.html)'s "Force Uninstall" feature (the normal one didn't do anything, since all files had already been removed) found two registry keys and removed them. Problem solved.

Okay, I could have searched the registry myself for the string, but I wasn't sure if that was all, and since I had previously destroyed a Windows 8.1 installation by removing registry keys I was reluctant to do so.